# Attaching generated zip file to e-mail

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I am trying to create a system to issue reports for our customers. For that purpose, I have created a class that uploads the results of the stock take into the cloud (users are able to access their reports online as well). However, I am running into a couple of issues that I can't resolve.

So, issue number 1. I am generating a zip file using a simple function:

```
public function generateReports($emailAddress)
{
    ?>
    <script>
    var url = '<?php echo Navigation::gUrl('/users/admin/reportspack.php', array('stocktake_id' => $this->stocktake_id));?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            timeout: 5000,
            {}

        });
        </script>
        <?
        echo "<h2>Reports generated and saved in a ZIP folder.</h2>";
}
```

The next part of the function is attaching the file to the e-mail:

```
require_once "/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php";
    //require_once "mime.php";
    $query = "SELECT s.store_name AS store_name, s.supervisor_name AS supervisor_name ,DATE_FORMAT(s.stocktake_date, '%d/%l/%Y') AS stocktake_date, u.username AS username, u.password AS password
                    FROM stocktakes s 
                    INNER JOIN users u ON u.company_id = s.sms_customer_id
                    WHERE stocktake_id = '{$this->stocktake_id}'
                      ";
    //echo $query;
    //die();
    $result = $this->dbClient->query($query);;
    $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $file = 'C:/Reports/Reports'.$this->stocktake_id.'.zip';
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('lh233.dnsireland.com', 465, 'ssl')
        ->setUsername('from@email.address')
        ->setPassword('notsharingmypassword');

    $from = 'from@email.address';
    $to = $emailAddress;
    //echo $to;
    //die();
    //$subject ='Test stocktake summary reports' ;
    $body = "Hello,\n\nPlease find attached reports for your most recent stocktake carried out at " . $row['store_name'] ."\n\n These reports have also been uploaded to the customer portal and can be accessed by logging in to http://reports.stocktaking.ie/ using the following credentials:\n\nusername:".$row['username']." \n\npassword:".$row['password']."\n\nShould you have any queries, please do not hesitate to contact me.\n\nKind Regards,\n\n ". $row['supervisor_name'] ."\n\n <<HOLDER FOR STOCKTAKING.IE SIGNATURE>>";

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance("".$row['store_name'].",Stocktake Summary Reports, ".$row['stocktake_date']."")
    ->setFrom(array($from => $row['supervisor_name']))
  ->setTo(array($to, $to => $row['store_name']))
  ->setBody($body)
  ;
    $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($file));
    //echo $message;
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    echo $result;
    if ($result != 1) {
         echo('<p>Error when sending the e-mail.</p>');
     } else {
         echo('<h2>Message successfully sent!</h2>');
     }
```

The first time when I try to issue the reports, I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_IoException' with message 'Unable to open file for reading [C:/Reports/Reports4074.zip]' in C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php:144 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php(84): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->_getReadHandle() #1 C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\ContentEncoder\Base64ContentEncoder.php(43): Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream->read(8192) #2 C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(547): Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder_Base64ContentEncoder->encodeByteStream(Object(Swift_ByteStream_FileByteStream), Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer), 0, 78) #3 C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\SimpleMimeEntity.php(522): Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity->_bodyToByteStream(Object(Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer)) #4 C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Simple in C:\Apache\htdocs\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\ByteStream\FileByteStream.php on line 144

This kind of suggest that the zip file is still generating while trying to attach it to the e-mail, which shouldn't be the case? The code should wait for the generation to finish completely? I even tried having the e-mail part as a separate function and calling it after generating the zip file, but got the same end result. When I refresh the page straight away, the zip folder is attached and e-mail is sent.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Shouldn't the path separator be the other way around for a local file? (`\ ` instead of `/`)

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunatelly.. Just thinking, could it be caused by the "Timeout" value? Generating the zip file more than likely does take more than 5000ms (I presume those are ms?). If that time elapses, it just continues with the code, since it times out right?

Comment: Check the docs, but usually setting a timeout value to `0` reverts to default and might do the trick (if that is the problem of course)